# Multiple y axes with custom label in core plot

Tags: ios, core-plot

```
-(void)configureAxes {

CPTGraph* graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;    
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
CPTScatterPlot* plot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
plot.dataSource = self;
[graph addPlot:plot toPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace];       

[plotSpace setXRange: [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat( 0 ) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat( 8 )]];
[plotSpace setYRange: [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat( 0 ) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat( 10 )]];

self.arrayData=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"10",@"20",@"E", nil];
self.arrayDataY=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"CP",@"BD",@"Test",@"Notes",@"CM",@"Day",@"97.7",@"97.8",@"97.9", nil];

CPTMutableLineStyle *yMajorGridLineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
yMajorGridLineStyle.lineCap = kCGLineCapRound;
yMajorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
yMajorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0;


CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle=[CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
lineStyle.lineColor=[CPTColor redColor];
lineStyle.lineWidth=2.0f;

CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle1=[CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
lineStyle1.lineColor=[CPTColor greenColor];
lineStyle1.lineWidth=2.0f;

CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle2=[CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
lineStyle2.lineColor=[CPTColor blackColor];
lineStyle2.lineWidth=1.0f;

CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;

NSMutableArray  *labelTick=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6", nil];
x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
x.majorIntervalLength= CPTDecimalFromInteger(1);
x.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
x.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
x.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle1;
x.axisLineStyle = lineStyle2;
x.minorTickLength = 2.0f;
x.majorTickLength = 3.0f;
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal=CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0);
x.majorTickLocations=[NSSet setWithArray:labelTick];
x.visibleRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat([arrayDataY count])];
x.gridLinesRange=[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat( 0 ) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat( [arrayDataY count] )];
x.labelOffset=30.0f;
x.majorGridLineStyle = yMajorGridLineStyle;
CGFloat dateCount = [self.arrayData count];
NSMutableSet *xLabels = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];
NSMutableSet *xLocations = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];
NSInteger i = 0;
for (NSString *d in self.arrayData)
{
    NSLog(@":%@",d);

    CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:d  textStyle:axisSet.xAxis.labelTextStyle];
    //        [label setRotation:45.0];
    CGFloat location = i++;
    label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(location);
    label.offset = axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength;
    //label.rotation = M_PI/4;
    if (label) {
        [xLabels addObject:label];
        [xLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location]];
    }
}

x.axisLabels=xLabels;

CPTMutableLineStyle *gridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
gridLineStyle.dashPattern=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:2],nil];    


CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;

NSMutableArray  *ylabelTick=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8", nil];

y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
y.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromInteger(0.5);
y.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
y.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
y.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle1;
y.axisLineStyle = lineStyle2;
y.minorTickLength = 3.0f;
y.majorTickLength = 5.0f;
y.labelOffset=10.0f;    
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal=CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0);
y.majorTickLocations=[NSSet setWithArray:ylabelTick];
y.visibleRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat([arrayDataY count])];
y.gridLinesRange=[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat( 0 ) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat([arrayData count] )];
y.majorGridLineStyle=gridLineStyle;
CGFloat dateCounty = [self.arrayData count];
NSMutableSet *yLabels = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCounty];
NSMutableSet *yLocations = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCounty];
NSInteger j = 0;
for (NSString *d in self.arrayDataY)
{
    CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:d  textStyle:axisSet.yAxis.labelTextStyle];
    //        [label setRotation:45.0];
    CGFloat location = j++;
    label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(location);
    label.offset = axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLength;
    if (j<7) {
        [label setAlignment:CPTAlignmentBottom];
    }

    //label.rotation = M_PI/4;
    if (label) {
        [yLabels addObject:label];
        [yLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location]];
    }
}

y.axisLabels=yLabels;

CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace2 =[[CPTXYPlotSpace alloc] init];
plotSpace2.xRange = plotSpace.xRange;

plotSpace2.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat([arrayDataY count])];

[plotSpace2 setAllowsUserInteraction:YES];
[graph addPlotSpace:plotSpace2];


CPTXYAxis *y2 = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init];
y2.plotSpace    =plotSpace2;
y2.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
y2.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat([arrayData count]);
y2.majorTickLineStyle=lineStyle;
y2.minorTickLineStyle=lineStyle1;
y2.axisLineStyle = lineStyle2;
y2.minorTicksPerInterval = 2;
y2.majorIntervalLength   = CPTDecimalFromInteger(1);
y2.minorTickLength=5;
y2.coordinate          =CPTCoordinateY;        
y2.labelOffset                 = -30.0f;
y2.majorTickLocations=[NSSet setWithArray:ylabelTick];
y2.visibleRange                = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat([arrayDataY count])];
y2.axisLabels=yLabels;

graph.axisSet.axes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, y, y2, nil];
```

}

Please help me to add multiple y axis with custom label. also i want same x axis values in top of graph also (i.e. have two x axes, one at the top and one at the bottom).

[image]
In above image y2 axis label not showing. How to set y2 axis label with custom label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct. All you need now is to create more axes and add them to the axis set. In my example I created an indicator line that moves with the mouse pointer when the mouse is over the graph. You can easily adjust that for fixed x and y axes (see the `.coordinate` member to determine what type of axis it should be).

```
// The second y axis is used as the current location identifier.
mainIndicatorLine = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init];
mainIndicatorLine.hidden = YES;
mainIndicatorLine.coordinate = CPTCoordinateY;
mainIndicatorLine.plotSpace = plotSpace;
mainIndicatorLine.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset: 0];
mainIndicatorLine.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
mainIndicatorLine.separateLayers = YES;
mainIndicatorLine.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 6;
mainIndicatorLine.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;

CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
lineStyle.lineWidth = 1;
lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor colorWithGenericGray: 64 / 255.0];
lineStyle.lineCap = kCGLineCapRound;
lineStyle.dashPattern = @[@10.0f, @5.0f];
mainIndicatorLine.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
mainIndicatorLine.majorTickLineStyle = nil;

// Add the mainIndicatorLine to the axis set.
// It is essential to first assign the axes to be used in the arrayWithObject call
// to local variables or all kind of weird things start showing up later (mostly with invalid coordinates).
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (id)mainGraph.axisSet;
CPTXYAxis    *x = axisSet.xAxis;
CPTXYAxis    *y = axisSet.yAxis;
axisSet.axes = @[x, y, mainIndicatorLine];
```

Comment: Thanks Mike Lischke for your reply. In y2 axis not showing the custom label(ie y2.axisLabels=yLabels;). how to show custom label in y2 axis

Comment: @Jithin, look up the properties of the axis, e.g. labelingPolicy and also the label styles. In my example I did not need labels, hence I switched them off. But you have the setup for your other axes. Just apply the same logic on additional axes.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Now i got it

Comment: @Jithin, please accept my answer then (set the checkmark under the vote count). I see you have so far not accepted a single answer. If you have problems with that just ask me for help.